# Auto choose, populate and click

Tags: phantomjs

I want to load the page https://game.ultimate-bridge.com/table/ in PhantomJS, choose tournament or 4-hand, populate table and board and then click the load hand.

I have mainly tried to click the button "Load Hand" but not even that is going well.

```
if ("complete" === readyState) {
    console.log("if " + readyState);

    var x = document.getElementById("root").querySelectorAll(".jss7.jss46.jss51");
    x.click();
    console.log("klick");
} // if-statement
```

The button do not get clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
page.evaluate(function() {
var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
ev.initEvent("click", true, true);
document.querySelector("div.jss7.jss46.jss51 button[type='submit']").dispatchEvent(ev);
});
```